# How to pass selected data from one screen to another using ViewModel in Jetpack Compose? (In backward)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an Android app with Jetpack Compose, and I'm facing an issue with passing selected data from one screen to another using a ViewModel.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Screen A has a click listener that opens Screen B.
2. Screen B displays a list of items, and the user can select one item.
3. Upon selecting an item in Screen B, I want to pass the selected data back to Screen A using a ViewModel.

   ```
   class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   private val _selectedMusicItem = MutableStateFlow<MusicItem?>(null)
   val selectedMusicItem = _selectedMusicItem.asStateFlow()

    fun updateSelectedMusicItem(musicItem: MusicItem) {
   _selectedMusicItem.value = musicItem
   }
   }
   ```

In Screen B, I'm updating the selected data in the ViewModel like this:

```
viewModel.updateSelectedMusicItem(selectedMusicItem)
navController.navigateUp()
```

And in Screen A, I'm trying to observe the selected data like this:

```
val selectedMediaListState by viewModel.selectedMusicItem.collectAsState()
```

However, the selected data isn't updating in Screen A when I navigate back from Screen B.

Can anyone help me understand how to correctly pass selected data from one screen to another using a ViewModel in Jetpack Compose? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How are you initializing viewmodel? If the viewmodel is shared, it should be initialized with activity lifecycle. ```by activityViewModels()```

Comment: can you give me reference or something

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple approach to pass the data.

*(in your case , idk about your viewmodel implementation so)*

**In the Navigation page**

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(){
 var selectedMusicItem by remember{ mutableStateOf<MusicItem?>(null) }

NavHost(navcontrol, startDestination = "screenA"){

 composable(route = "screenA"){
 ScreenA(navController,musicItem = selectedMusicItem)
 }

 composable(route = "screenB"){
 ScreenB(navController,selectedMusicItem = { music ->
  //call back from selected item
  selectedMusicItem = music
  })
 }

 }
}
```

and  screenA and screenB composables are

```
 @Composable
fun ScreenA(navController: NavController,musicItem: MusicItem? ){
Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(route = "ScreenB") }) {

 }
}
@Composable
fun ScreenB(navController: NavController, selectedMusicItem: (MusicItem) -> 
Unit){
Button(
    onClick = {
        //here i pass the object as inside of callback
        selectedMusicItem(MusicItem.First)
        navController.navigate(route = "ScreenA")
    }
) {
    Text(text = "select First MusicItem")
}
}
```

using this solution wont cause any issues, but over using may cause **CallbackHell** , only use the solution if you can't find any other better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my version of answer yo my question. **I've solved my problem without viewmodel it's one of the navigation approach**

I've `MusicItem.kt` a data class.

> I've used `gson` library to serialize and deserialized my data class
> for conversion of object to string.

here is my navgraph code

```
ScreenA(
        navController,
        viewModel,
        musicFromResult = it.savedStateHandle.get<String>("music") ?: "",
    )
}
```

I'm handling state using this varible

> ```
>         musicFromResult = it.savedStateHandle.get<String>("music") ?: "",
> ```

Screen B where i want to update my data and go back to Screen A with updated data of screen B

```
 val gson = Gson()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(musicItem)
    navController.apply {
        popBackStack()
        currentBackStackEntry
            ?.savedStateHandle
            ?.set(
                "music",
                jsonString.toString(),
            )
    }
```

here I'm converting my string data to object again to use it wisely in screen A

```
   @Composable
   fun  ScreenA(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: FinalPostViewModel,
    musicFromResult: String = "",
   ) {
    val gson = Gson()
    var deserializedMusicItem by remember { mutableStateOf<MusicItem?>(null) }
    try {
        deserializedMusicItem = gson.fromJson(musicFromResult, MusicItem::class.java)
     } catch (e: Exception) {
        deserializedMusicItem = null
        e.printStackTrace()
     }
  }
```

now i've data in this varible `deserializedMusicItem` i can use it in my screen a to get data.